# windows 7 and ubuntu wont boot after trying to boot ubuntu

Tags: boot

I tried to boot Ubuntu through a DVD disc because I forgot my password

Ubuntu started booting when all of a sudden there was a black screen with a lot of text in it
which said failure and other stuff at the bottom(I don't have a picture or anything about what was written there)

so I have shut the computer down in order to try again but nor the Ubuntu or my windows will load please help me I don't know what to do its just a black screen all the time!

Comment: Check your bios settings for order of boot devices; What does "nor the Ubuntu or my windows will load" mean? what do you see on the screen? any error?

Answer (score 0):

you should reinstall your boot loader.

I suggest you to try this:
[restore the windows boot loader](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/)